# How to display android device screen on laptop

Tags: android, screen, connect

How to display android device screen on laptop which is further connected with the projector so that I can give the demo of my app ?

I have used **droid2screen**.
But it is very slow and working properly.

Is there any other *method* or *tool* which can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awindinc.sphone2tv

It's basically does what you want. Just make sure your PC and phone is in the same LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out this, [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en)

This allows you to access and manage your Android phone or tablet from Windows, Mac or the Web, wirelessly, for free. Transfer files between your devices, and share files to your friends.